# elasticsearch: creating inner queries

Tags: elasticsearch

here are my logs:

**index: purchase**

```
{details: { name: john, corID: 12345678 }}
{details: { name: bill, corID: 96657545}}

{town: NY, ID: 12345678 }
{a:b , v: g}
{a: hi, b: 12345678}
{g:f , k:ggg777 }
```

I would like to create a query which for a given name, the query will search in `purchase` index  for `details.name=<name>` ,  extract `details.corID` and search in the indexe for logs which contain  the `details.corID`

example for above details:

**name = "john"**

**query result:**
(all logs which have `12345678`)

```
{details: { name: john, corID: 12345678 }}
{town: NY, ID: 12345678 }
{a: hi, b: 12345678}
```

**EDIT**

this is how I would do it in SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM purchase
where  corID= 
     (SELECT details.corID 
      FROM [purchase]
      where  details.name = "john")
```

Comment: I think you have a design issue here. You're trying to perform a join query accross multiple indexes. If you need to do such a query, it means your documents should be embedded/nested inside your `purchase` documents and not in split in different indexes. According to [ELS documentation about "Joining queries"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/joining-queries.html) *Performing full SQL-style joins in a distributed system like Elasticsearch is prohibitively expensive.*

Comment: I am searching over logs from different services, can't change design,

Comment: I understand. You should probably consider to perform two queries instead of one.

Comment: theres no way to have one automated query?